# onMouseLeave event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

This is nav component. This nav component rendered at run time. Text should be visible when mouse will enter to div with ref "text_nav" and text should hide when mouse will leave div with ref "text_nav".

`onMouseLeave` is not working

```
var React = require('React');
var $ = require('jquery');

var Nav = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        this.serverRequest =
        $.post("/nav", {}, function(result) {
            _this.setState({
                items: result.data
            });
        })
    },

   onMouseEnter: function() {
        this.refs.text_navigator.style = {display: true}
    },
   onMouseLeave: function() {
        this.refs.text_navigator.style = {display: 'none'}
    },
    render: function() {
        var text = this.state.items.map(function(data, index) {
            var icon = "text_" + data.sname;
            return (
                    <div id={icon} key={index} className="text_nav_item">
                            <p>
                                <span><a href={data.url}>{data.title} </a></span>
                            </p>
                     </div>
            );
        });

        return (
                <div id="nav" className="fixed" style={{zIndex: 1018}} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
                    <div id="text_nav" ref="text_navigator" style={{display: 'none'}} >
                        <div id="text_nav_content">
                            {item_text}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the ref is `text_nav` in your render method, not `text_navigator` as you're using in `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`. But the main issue is that you can't set the display style the way you're trying to do, as
`this.refs.text_navigator.style = {display: true}`

The most common approach to take is to set a boolean in state, perhaps called `displayTextNavigator`. In `getInitialState`, set it to false, and then your `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` functions can be:

```
  onMouseEnter: function() {
        this.setState({ displayTextNavigator: true})
    },
   onMouseLeave: function() {
        this.setState({ displayTextNavigator: false})
    },
```

Now in your render method, you can change your wrapping div to look like this:

`<div id="text_nav" ref="text_nav" style={{display: this.state.displayTextNavigator ? 'block': 'none'}} >`
You can pull that ternary operator out to earlier in the render method if you'd like it be more readable.